# How to solve Text overflowing?

Tags: flutter

I'm facing issue with text overflowing. When I use long text it behaves like this

> OverFlowing 231 pxels

[image: rt]

How to fit Text in nice way?

I tried to use `FittedBox` widget but text becomew small. And tried to use `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` but it crops the text so only some text is shown.

Also using `\n` is not an option because you have to add it manually.

I want it like this:

[image]

the code for Text is:

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "${widget.snapshot['title']}",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 29,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 11.0,
        ),
        Text(
          "${widget.snapshot['subtitle']}",
          maxLines: 1,
          softWrap: true,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontSize: 15,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 11.0,
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              disabledColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: null,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "${widget.snapshot['likes']} ",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "${widget.snapshot['title']}",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 29,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 11.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 11.0,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  disabledColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: null,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "${widget.snapshot['likes']} ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
``
```

Comment: Yes its work without overflowing , Can you please explain how you did it ?

Comment: No need for the **Row** I just kept every widget in a single column and since column does not care about the width of any child i.e (it clips the widget itself if it is text) unlike Row

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you need a Row() or not.  As Josteve pointed out, in this particular case you don't.  It served no purpose.  So a Column() will wrap it.

But there are of course plenty of times you need Row() content to potentially wrap.  In which case you can enclose the widget (inside the Row list) most likely to overflow in an Expanded().